# VBA Combobox not populating recordset

Tags: vba, excel

I have a SQL query pulling back two columns and populating an ActiveX Combobox. The query in SQL returns a single row of data, however when I select the combobox in Excel the list is empty.

This is the part of the code that populates the combobox:

```
With rst
    Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing 'Disconnect the recordset.
    k = .Fields.Count
          'Populate the array with the whole recordset.
    vaData = .GetRows
End With

CB_Layer.List = Application.Transpose(vaData)
```

To test this I have added a watch to the rst and can see that I have one row of values. As soon as I pass over the vaData = .GetRows the watch value changes to:

```
: Value : <Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.>
```

Can anyone advise why this is happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it make sense to disconnect the recordset BEFORE getting the rows?  I honestly don't know, I'm not really too familiar with this code.

Comment: I think releasing the connection is ok as the record set will still hold the data?

Comment: You could try moving the `Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing` line after the `vaData = .GetRows` line to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks Derek, this didn't change anything. As soon as I step over the vaData command the error occurs

Comment: i think that GetRows moves the pointer to end of recordset.  you need to use a command to retrieve first row ... it is something like `rst.MoveFirst` (i do not remember the exact command at the moment)

Comment: and i think that you have to do `rst.MoveLast` (or something like that), then check number of records ... then `rst.MoveFirst` should give you the first record. ... btw: you are counting fields instead of records